# RC Timing Circuit with Power Control for Drone Flight Modes?

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-analysis, switches, timer

Recently, I came across an intriguing circuit design in AOE 3rd edition that inspired me to try it out. The idea is to design a simple circuit that activates an LED for precisely 60 seconds after a momentary push button is pressed, and I decided to give it a try. In my case, I wanted to attach an NMOS to either block or flow current to the rest of the circuit. I am currently in the process of developing my own flight controller for a drone and I wanted it to have two flight modes, timed and untimed flight.

The foundation of the design is an RC timing circuit coupled with a comparator. The (-) input of the comparator is held at 37% of my input voltage (11.1V), resulting in a reference voltage of approximately 4.1V. When the push button is pressed, the capacitor should charge rapidly to 11.1V (achieving a rise time of approximately 10 ms), driving the comparator output high, which turns on the N Channel Mosfet. After releasing the button, the capacitor discharges exponentially with a time constant of 60 seconds (I'll be using different resistor and capacitor values to achieve this), causing the comparator output to return to a low state, turning off the NMOS.

I'm also trying have another switch which should allow current to flow directly to bypass the RC timing filter for "untimed flight". I have tried running this on a few online circuit simulators, but results haven't been as successful. Wondering if it was due to the circuit simulator or the values of my RC timing circuit.

Would this circuit work? If so, are there any potential improvements or changes that could enhance the circuit's performance? If not, where would the error be?

It is my first time building such a circuit so all feedback would be greatly appreciated. Regards!

[image]

Comment: "RC timing circuit" and "precisely" do not belong together in the same thought. If you're working on a flight controller for a drone then you already have a fairly powerful MCU - use that for this timing exercise.

Comment: It isn't working because there are many errors in your schematic. The power for the comparator is backwards, Q1 appears to be shorting out the power supply, etc.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to experiment with a simple timing circuit for the project. I'll definitely take the MCU into account.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for pointing out. I've flipped the comparator and connected source of NMOS to ground.

Comment: Even with Q1 flipped around, all it can ever do is (briefly) sort the supply to ground.

Comment: SW1 & SW2 preform exactly the same function. They're both connected to the same nodes in the circuit.

Comment: If neither of the buttons are pressed, what powers the comparator?

Comment: 100R and 60R are exceptionally low values for a voltage-divider, unless you're trying to burn off a lot of energy as heat.

Comment: @brhans For the switches should I add a OR logic gate in the junction of the node where SW1 and SW2 are connected to?

Comment: SW1 & SW2 are connected together on both sides (one 'wire' is just longer than the other), so I don't know which node you're referring to. It's also not clear to me what you intend to achieve with that OR gate or what would power it.

Comment: @brhans As for the comparator, i'd assume that I would need a pull down resistor to stabilize the comparator. Where should it be added?

Comment: You could add a pull-down resistor pretty much anywhere you'd like in that circuit, but I don't know what you mean by "to stabilize the comparator". Why do you think it needs to be stabilized? That kind of circuit (if all the other issues were resolved) would benefit from some positive feedback in order to introduce hysteresis around the switching point, but that's got nothing to do with pull-down resistors.

Comment: I was referring to the node before the SDVR_VIN pin. If I were to "separate" the wires and not have both of them join at a node, would that work? I intended to use an OR logic gate to differentiate the functions of the switches and get the current to flow based on the state of either switch.

Comment: You're right; I misspoke regarding the term "stabilize the comparator." My intention was to address hysteresis and improve the reliability of the circuit's switching behavior. I apologize for any confusion caused.